# OnTouch on google maps removes the drag and scroll in mapview as well as zoom controls dont appear ontouch

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

ok as the question says I have a mapview and a OnTouchListener set to it and in the Ontouch function i set a overlay image on the map. But in this process now the zoom controls and drag functionality in the mapview is removed somehow. please help me out with it.
I have already setzoomcontrolson to true (no effect). Help please.

```
public class marker extends ItemizedOverlay {

    Context mContext;

    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    Drawable marker;

    private int xDragImageOffset=0;

    private int yDragImageOffset=0;

    private int xDragTouchOffset=0;

    private int yDragTouchOffset=0;

    OverlayItem inDrag;

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public marker(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {

          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

          mContext = context;

          marker=defaultMarker;
        } 

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {

        mOverlays.clear();

        mOverlays.add(overlay);

        populate();
    }

    @Override

    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {

       return mOverlays.get(i);
    }



        @Override

    public int size() {

    return mOverlays.size();
    }

        @Override

    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView){

    boolean tappedAnOverlay = super.onTap(geoPoint, mapView);

        if (tappedAnOverlay) {

            places.gp=geoPoint;  // do your thing if hit an overlay

        }

        else {
            // no overlay found in that location
        }


        MapController mc=mapView.getController();

        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);

            return true;
    }



}
this is my marker overlays file
```

and

```
    public class places extends MapActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener/*,OnTouchListener*/  {

        MapView mapView;

        MapController mc;

        Button srchbtn;

        EditText searchstring;

        marker itemizedoverlay;

    public static List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

        OverlayItem overlayitem;

        public static GeoPoint gp;

        Button back;

        String s1;

        String s2="yourprofile";

        String s3="partnerprofile";

        public int zoom=5;

        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.place);

            mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            srchbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);

            searchstring=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edplnm);

            srchbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            mapView.setClickable(true);

            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

            itemizedoverlay = new marker(drawable, this);

            back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbk);

            back.setOnClickListener(this);

            s1=getIntent().getStringExtra("ClassName");

            mc=mapView.getController();

            mc.setZoom(zoom);

            gp=new GeoPoint((int)(21.7679 * 1E6), (int)(78.8718 * 1E6));

            mc.animateTo(gp);

                   // mapView.setOnTouchListener(this);


        }

     @Override

        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

            return false;
        }

        @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(arg0.getId())

            {

            case R.id.searchbtn:String s = searchstring.getText().toString();

                                String[] vals =s.split(":");

                                float lat;

                                float logi;

                                lat=Float.parseFloat(vals[0]);

                                logi=Float.parseFloat(vals[1]);

                                gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(logi * 1E6));

                                MapController mc=mapView.getController();

                                mc.setZoom(80);

                                mc.animateTo(gp);

                                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(gp, "", "");

                                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

                                mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

                                break;

            case R.id.btnbk: int Lat;

                             int Logi;

                             Lat=gp.getLatitudeE6();

                             Logi=gp.getLongitudeE6();

                             boolean val=s1.equals(s2);

                             boolean val2=s1.equals(s3);

                             Intent I1=new Intent(places.this,yourprofile.class);

                             Intent I2=new Intent(places.this,partnerprofile.class);

                             if(val)

                             {

                             I1.putExtra("LAT",Lat);

                             I1.putExtra("LONG",Logi);

                             setResult(RESULT_OK,I1); 

                             finish();


                             }else

                                 if(val2)

                                 {

                                     I2.putExtra("LAT",Lat);

                                     I2.putExtra("LONG",Logi);

                                     setResult(RESULT_OK,I2); 

                                     finish();
                                 }

                             break;


            }

    }

    /*public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

             Projection p =((MapView)v).getProjection();

             gp = p.fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());

             overlayitem = new OverlayItem(gp, "", "");

             itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

             mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

             mc.setZoom(zoom);

             mc.animateTo(gp);

             searchstring.setText(((float)gp.getLatitudeE6())/1000000 + ":" +

    ((float)gp.getLongitudeE6())/1000000);

            }

            return true;
        }*/



    }
```

this is my places class file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [Sample Working Demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch) which you may want to Use.

It will help you to Drag&Drop the Image with Zooming and Touch Functionality for Mapview.

Hope it will Help.